# Copy file to clipboard via command-line

Tags: command-line, clipboard, copy-and-paste

I have a very long path to a PDF file:

```
foo/bar/blu/one/two/something/blabla/file.pdf
```

I see the above path in my terminal.

Now I want to copy+paste this file (the PDF, not the filename) into a chat-application.

Is there a simple way to get this PDF copy-and-pasted?

I found this solution:

```
nautilus foo/bar/blu/one/two/something/blabla/file.pdf
```

Then drag+drop the file.

Is there a way without using a GUI application like nautilus?

Comment: Do you want the *text* of the PDF copied, or does the chat application allow file uploads with drag and drop? If the latter, it may depend on how the chat application works, What is it?

Comment: The chat application allows file uploads. I want to upload the PDF not text.

Comment: You don't want to tell us what it is?

Comment: @frabjous you want to know what kind of chat-application it is? Does it matter for this question? I just want to name a commercial product here, which I would like to replace with an open source solution (if I could).

Comment: I'm not sure I can personally help regardless, but I suspect people might be more likely to help if (1) they can investigate how drag and drop is implemented in the application, and (2) they can test for themselves. I'm really not sure, however.

Comment: see if my answer works for you; if not I'll delete it or try to find more on it

Answer (score 0):

For X11: [xclip](https://github.com/astrand/xclip)

```
find /foo/bar/blu/one/two/something/blabla/ -name "file.pdf"| xclip -i -selection clipboard -t text/uri-list
```

For Wayland [wl-clipboard](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard):

```
wl-copy < /foo/bar/blu/one/two/something/blabla/file.pdf
```

wl-copy uses xdg-mime to get the type of the file.

Comment: `...  | xclip -i -selection clipboard -t text/uri-list` did not work for me (I use x11). In Nautilus and in the chat-application, I can't insert the file like this.